# virtual box : can not access host system's wamp phpmyadmin from guest system's browser

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed a virtual box and in it I installed Windows 7. My host machine is running on XP. I want to access my magento project from guest operating system's browser(ie 9) but i am unable to do it. Though i can access wamp index page and phpinfo (by using host machines ip). Its only when i try to access my magento project files or phpmyadmin, browser will show message 'cannot display the webpage'.

Can some one tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there's no security setting set to block requests coming from anywhere else then localhost (127.0.0.1), just like a firewall. You'll need to allow the host machine virtual network card IP address.

example of a blocking setting in phpMyAdmin:
http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/18-php/65-allowing-only-local-users-to-phpmyadmin

example of a blocking setting in Apache:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-restrict-access-based-on-ip-address-to-selected-directories/

I don't magento, but there's a big chance that there's a similar setting.

Comment: sorry for replying too late (precisely after 5 days). 

I didn't find (may be i didnt unders'd) any particular answer to my problem by following your links but it helped a lot to understand what could be the problem so thanks a lot.

I found an ans to the problem of 'accessing phpmyadmin from VB' on 

http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2009/05/26/faq-how-to-fix-error-403-access-forbidden-for-phpmyadmin-in-wampserver/

 
and now i can access index.php of my magneto project by changing 
admin -> system -> configuration -> web -> Base URL with your IP.
once again thanks a lot for answering to my question.